# How can I make a call on button click event in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin

I have a service class

```
public async Task LoginAsync(string userName, string password)
{
   var model = new
   {
       phoneNum = userName,
       passwordUs = password
   };
   .............
}
```

Page1.xaml.cs. This is how I call the service class

```
private ApiServices _apiServices = new ApiServices();
public ICommand LoginCommand { get; set; }
async void btone_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   LoginCommand = new Command(async () => {
      await _apiServices.LoginAsync(txtone.Text, txttwo.Text);
   });
}
```

Looks like my code is wrong, so it doesn't call the service class

I want when button click event it will call `LoginAsync`

I have created a ViewModel, and that works fine, however I don't want to go through the ViewModel. (Maybe for some reason I want to check right where the button click event is). Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are creating a command - this is only needed if you want to bind a command to a button, it is not needed when assigning an event handler

```
async void btone_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   LoginCommand = new Command(async () => {
      await _apiServices.LoginAsync(txtone.Text, txttwo.Text);
   });
}
```

instead just call the method directly

```
async void btone_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   await _apiServices.LoginAsync(txtone.Text, txttwo.Text);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your xaml

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="YourNameSpace.LoginPage"
             xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:YourNameSpace.ViewModels">
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <viewmodel:LoginPageViewModel></viewmodel:LoginPageViewModel>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>                    
                    <Entry Placeholder="Username" Text="{Binding Username}" />                    
                    <Entry Placeholder="Password" Text="{Binding Password}" /> 
                    <Button Text="Login" Command="{Binding LoginCommand}" />                       
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Add this in your view model

```
namespace YourNameSpace.ViewModels
{
    public class LoginPageViewModel
    {
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        private ApiServices _apiServices = new ApiServices();
        public ICommand LoginCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return new Command(async () =>
                {
                    await _apiServices.LoginAsync(txtone.Text, txttwo.Text);
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I solved the problem with the help of Jason above. Thank you very much